# Use Hazelcast IMap at Hazelcast Jet Processor

Tags: java, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

I'm just start to learn Hazelcast Jet.
My source is UDP datagrams. I want to process it in parallel at some nodes of Jet and resend them to other addresses by 'domain'.
I want to use Hazelcast IMDG IMap with loader to get 'domain' by 'source ip'.

```
DAG dag = new DAG();        
Vertex source = dag.newVertex("datagram-source",
                UdpSocketP.supplier("0.0.0.0", 41813));
        source.localParallelism(1);

        Vertex mapper = dag.newVertex("map",
                map(new DomainMapper(instance.getMap("mysqlNas"))));

        Vertex sink = dag.newVertex("sink",
                Sinks.writeFile("logs"));
        sink.localParallelism(1);
```

But when I try to use IMap at DistributedFunction i get exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "metaSupplier" must be serializable
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:185)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.Vertex.<init>(Vertex.java:101)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.Vertex.<init>(Vertex.java:78)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.DAG.newVertex(DAG.java:79)
    at org.eltex.softwlc.sorm.replicator.JetServer.main(JetServer.java:46)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.hazelcast.jet.stream.impl.MapDecorator
```

DomainMapper code:

```
package org.eltex.softwlc.sorm.replicator;

import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.jet.function.DistributedFunction;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;

/**
 * Created by mickey on 21.07.17.
 */
public class DomainMapper implements DistributedFunction<DatagramPacket, IpData>, Serializable {

    private final IMap<String, NasValue> map;

    public DomainMapper(IMap<String, NasValue> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public IpData apply(DatagramPacket datagramPacket) {
        final IpData d = new IpData(datagramPacket, datagramPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());
        System.out.println(d);

        final NasValue nasValue = map.get(datagramPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());
        if (nasValue!=null) {
            d.setDomain(nasValue.getDomain());
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

What is my mistake?
Or Hazelcast Jet is wrong choice for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to serialize the entire `IMap` inside the function. A direct fix would be to write a custom processor that gets access to the Hazelcast Jet instance inside its `init()` method and looks up its IMap from that. Since `init()` code is executed on the target member, after all deserialization, this would work.

However, on a more general level your goal seems to be of the "data enrichment" kind. The way we want to support this in Jet is via a "hash join" operation, which is currently not first-class; however there is a code sample showing the approach. You can either funnel the entire `IMap` contents to a vertex that will turn it into a plain `HashMap` and distribute to all enriching processors, or you can prepare a Hazelcast `ReplicatedMap` that will be used directly by the enriching processor.

The first approach means you work against a snapshot of the `IMap`; in the second one you can continue to update the `ReplicatedMap` as the job is running.

It is best to go and check the samples: [HashMapEnrichment](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/0.4-maintenance/batch/enrichment/src/main/java/HashMapEnrichment.java) and [ReplicatedMapEnrichment](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/0.4-maintenance/batch/enrichment/src/main/java/ReplicatedMapEnrichment.java).

Comment: I have implemented 'DomainMapper extends AbstractProcessor' and override 'tryProcess' for it. dag.newVertex("map", DomainMapper.supplier()); works correct.

Comment: Beware that `IMap.get()` is a blocking call (possibly communicating with remote members), so in general calling it inside a cooperative processor would break its cooperativeness. You can declare the processor non-cooperative, but performance will still suffer (as opposed to the approaches I mention in the answer).